# Wordpress custom search form - ignore empty/default input fields upon submission?

Tags: wp-query, forms

I have a form I've developed that creates a WP_Query to search through a custom post type in Wordpress.

There are 4 fields: title, author, orderby(selectbox), order(selectbox)

Say the user types in "cats" in title and presses search, my URL will look like this:

```
?spot_title=cats&spot_author=&spot_orderby=date&spot_order=desc
```

I'd prefer to have the URL simply be

```
?spot_title=cat
```

Since the rest are the "default" values and/or blank. I'm not hooking this into JavaScript anywhere, but is that my only solution? I feel like WordPress would have a helper function for this somewhere.

The HTML for the form is a simple:

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="cpt-search-form" action="">
```

Comment: I’m afraid that html forms don’t work like that - all fields are sent and it’s normal behavior...

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż Might be "normal" but there is a way around it. I imagine a way to hook the form into a function. Parse it. And manually append query args if they're not "default values"

Comment: Forms doesn’t work that way. Form sends all its fields. You can’t “filter them” - filters are working on your server, and form works in browser and generates requests... So seriously - don’t mess with it - just process the request properly, as all internet is doing... I’m also sorry, but I’m afraid this question has not much to do with WP, so it’s off-topic in here, I guess...